# Retrieve Private SSH Key

Tags: ssh

How do i retrieve the private key so i can deploy to my server? (I'm trying to use the cloud66 deploy to your own server option, it asks for private key)

running

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

on my local machine gives me a private key, but it isn't being accepted.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

shows the public key, and i can see that public key is assigned to my server on digital ocean.

Comment: What do you mean with "not being accepted"?

Comment: @jornane - i mean when i paste it into the settings field on cloud66 i get "Sorry — Unable to save key. Are sure this is a valid private key."

Comment: DO NOT, EVER, POST YOUR PRIVATE KEY. NOT HERE, NOT ANYWHERE. NOT EVEN ON A VPS. You're supposed to get an error if you do that. ONLY post your public key. Your private key must lie safely in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and never be placed somewhere else.

Comment: @jornane  -ok .  maybe a badly named field on cloud66.  ill check with them.  it for sure says "Private SSH Key:"

Comment: I don't know what Cloud66 is, but chances are you don't need it. Just make sure the public key is available on your server and everything should work just fine.

Comment: i can ssh in myself from terminal.  cloud 66 is a deployment tool.  it's asking for that, it doesn't accept the private or public key.  odd.

Comment: http://www.cloud66.com/

Answer (score 7):

You're not supposed to upload your private key. **NEVER DO THAT**.

Only use your public key. If you give your public key to Digital Ocean or Cloud66 (whatever that may be), you should be able to login from any machine that has the private key. There is NO NEED for the remote server to know your private key.

Here is a nice tutorial about how SSH key authentication works: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/ssh-public-key-based-authentication-how-to.html

**EDIT** Looks like Cloud66 is some Dockery/PaaSy solution, which uses SSH for communication with the server. They have some documentation on how to set up SSH keys here: http://community.cloud66.com/articles/setting-up-ssh-keys.
It isn't clear what it uses these keys for, there's a mention of not supporting password-protected keys, which I think is weird. The rest of the document looks like a quite normal public key setup, although with some strange commands. There is no mention of having to input a private key somewhere, though.

I would still think that going with the cyberciti tutorial is the best way to go.

Comment: If it's dockery, paasy, devopsy then it's very likely to lack security ;)

Comment: I've followed similar docs on setting up keys and i can ssh to my server.  The issue is whatever Cloud66 is asking for is not being accepted.  Either because i'm pasting in the wrong thing or because there is an authorisation issue of some kind.  Thanks for your help @jonane ill take it up with Cloud66.

Answer (score 2):

You can't retrieve a private key, you either have it or you don't. You can retrieve the public key from the private with

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Note that command will overwrite your existing key so you might want to save it or choose a different output file. You could then compare the retrieved key with the one you already have and if they are different take appropriate action.

If they are the same then you probably need to tell us the exact error you are seeing.

Comment: if i have it, where would it be?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're describing the [procedure for uploading a private key](http://634-991-907.cloud66.net/deployment/deploy-to-your-own-server) to provide ssh-mediated access to an Ubuntu server which *you* administrate. Typically this would mean that you create a user account on that server, with permissions restricted (by sudo) to do *only* the activities that you'd want Cloud 66 to automate. Then create a private key for *that* user account (commands described in other answers, eg. by Iain).

Pasting your regular user's private key in there sounds like a big gap in the security chain. Thumbs down to Cloud 66 for not being very explicit about that.

Cloud 66 talks to Digital Ocean cloud deployments, but normally [uses OAuth for authentication](http://help.cloud66.com//deployment/digitalocean-cloud) and API methods to control them.

Without knowing your specific setup, it's difficult to be certain, but it sounds like you're trying to use the first (ssh) approach when you should be using the second (OAuth/API). If it's failing, you may have dodged a bullet.